# SQL Server - how to identify if table is heap or B-tree

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server - Is there a system table for identifying if my table is heap or b-tree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the catalog view [sys.partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) holds this information. The field `index_id` will tell you if a table is heap (index_id = 0) or b-tree (index_id > 0).

```
select 
    o.name, 
    o.object_id, 
    case 
      when p.index_id = 0 then 'Heap'
      when p.index_id = 1 then 'Clustered Index/b-tree'
      when p.index_id > 1 then 'Non-clustered Index/b-tree'
    end as 'Type'
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.partitions p on p.object_id = o.object_id
where name = 'YourTableName'
```

From the documentation - [Table and Index Organization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> ID of the index within the object to which this partition belongs.
>
> ```
> 0 = heap
> 1 = clustered index
> 2 or greater = nonclustered
> ```
>
> Heaps are tables that have no clustered index. Nonclustered indexes
>   have a B-tree index structure similar to the one in clustered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Each table that have't clustered index is a heap table.
you can check clustered index on each table in order to determine that table is a heap table or no.